# Could not interact with contract in BSC mainnet but succeed in testnet (but still a standard transfer)

Tags: smartcontracts, bsc

I may send raw transaction by sendSignedTransaction to contract address on BSC testnet, and it succeed but this is just a standard transaction; it's not contract call like I want.

But on BSC mainnet, it always failed with error: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Please help me check code below then tell me where issue, any comment, reply or guess welcome; many thanks.

For testnet, it always succeed but it was a a standard transaction, [link to image](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/18737397?key=1d73ebea3d8942f8d67fedc76b207cde). While I wanna interact with contract, result should show field **Interacted With (To)**

```
var minABI = [
{
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_claimer",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "_amount",
            "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
            "name": "_sig",
            "type": "bytes"
        }
    ],
    "name": "claim",
    "outputs": [],
    "payable": true,
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
}
];
var web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'); // testnet
//var web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org:443'); // mainnet
var _from = '0x2151...';
var _to = '0x7f617...';
var _sign = '0x5eddd...';
var PRIVATE_KEY = 'da65f...';

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, _to, {from: _from});

var _nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_from, 'latest');

var _signEncoded = contract.methods.claim(_nonce, '17390000000000000000', _sign).encodeABI();
var esGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
     "from"      : _from,
     "nonce"     : _nonce, 
     "to"        : _to,
     "data"      : _signEncoded
});

var sentValue = gasPrice * esGas;

var transaction = {
 'to': _to,
 'value': sentValue,
 'gas': esGas,
 'nonce': _nonce,
 'data': _signEncoded,
};

var signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction, PRIVATE_KEY);
var tx = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);
```

For mainet, if I used **_signEncoded** in **web3.eth.estimateGas** it returns error: **execution reverted: Invalid signature**, I must use **_sign** to send transaction but it still always failed with error **Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]** [link to image](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/18738144?key=427a63d9e3648ae31a0a4561619988dd)

```
var esGas = await web3.eth.estimateGas({
     "from"      : _from,
     "nonce"     : _nonce, 
     "to"        : _to,
     "data"      : _sign
});
```

Comment: What is the contract address?

Comment: contract address is var _to = '0x7f617...';

Comment: I meant the full contract address. My goal was to explore whether the contract is deployed on the testnet (as you're connecting to the testnet provider), and if it has a verified source code to check the code - if it doesn't, at least check if the `claim()` function exists, etc.

Comment: Contract deployed on mainnet but not verified. But I'm sure claim() exists and worked, because I used metamask to claim it normally, in transaction mainnet displayed function with parameters + data. Also I may use byte code decompiler of bscscan to see its claim function

Comment: 1 more thing if I want to call this claim, I must call via its contract: contract.methods.claim(_nonce, 'amount', _sign).call() ? sendSignedTransaction is just a normal transfer with data and could not be used in my case? Because I tried using MM then copied input data in MM popup then used sendSignedTransaction with copied data but still failed

Answer (score 0):

> *Contract deployed on mainnet*

But the JS snippet is trying to call the contract on testnet (where it's not deployed).

```
var web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'); // testnet
//var web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org:443'); // mainnet
```

So you need to either deploy it on testnet as well, or use a mainnet (where it's already deployed) web3 provider.

---

> *if I want to call this claim, I must call via its contract: contract.methods.claim(_nonce, 'amount', _sign).call() ? sendSignedTransaction is just a normal transfer and could not be used in my case?*

The `contract.methods.claim(...).call()` is an shorthad for calling the function. `sendSignedTransaction()` can be used to send a transaction - by default without invoking any function, but you can also define its `data` param to execute the `claim()` function.

Mind that there's a difference between a call (read-only; performed by the `functionName().call()` in web3) and a transaction (read-write; performed by the `functionName().send()` function in web3). Based on the context of your question, I'm guessing you want to **send** a transaction (executing the `claim()` function) - not perform a call (to the `claim()` function).

Comment: it's too weird, I used MM to copy input data, then **Returned error: unknown account** with code `var _sign = 'data copied from metamask'; contract.methods.claim(_from, 'amount', _sign).send();`

Comment: with `contract.methods.claim(_from, 'amount', _sign).call();` it returns **execution reverted: Invalid signature**

Comment: with `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction);` it returns **nonce too low**

Comment: thank you so much, just try 1 more time with `var _nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount('my address', 'latest');` it's successful. I MUST use **`nonce`** from live mainnet, not from website database